# How is useReducer implemented in ReactJs source code?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The [old docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#useyourimagination) give a rough idea of how `useReducer` is implemented:

```
function useReducer(reducer, initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  function dispatch(action) {
    const nextState = reducer(state, action);
    setState(nextState);
  }

  return [state, dispatch];
}
```

From the looks of it, it seems like calling multiple `dispatches` sequentially will mimic sequential calling of `setState`. Now we know that calling multiple `setState` without prevState will cause bugs as these calls are batched, e.g. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-dev-s27ysl?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js three setState in a row doesn't increase the counter by 3. A similar program, however, with `dispatch` cause the counter to increase by 3 instead: https://jsfiddle.net/ynfem670/1/

So this makes me beleive that the `useReducer` leviates `setSTate(funtction(prevState){...})` as following:

```
function useReducer(reducer, initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  function dispatch(action) {
    const nextState = reducer(state, action); //sort of uses prevState
    setState(prevState => nextState); //Note that reducer already applies 
                                      //logic to state so we don't need to mutate prevState. 
  }

  return [state, dispatch];
}
```

**Question 1:** How is `useReducer` implemented interally? Not the exact code but the general idea or pseudo code.

---

On a seperate note, I don't see any way to grab prevProps in either `useState` or `dispatch`, i.e., in class based ReactJs we have:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

Now hook based `setState` and `dispatch` doesn't get props parameter:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

One could argue that in function based components on every render we get live binding to props always. In that case why don't we use `this.props` in `this.setState((state, props)=>{/*this.props*/})`?

Comment: If you would like to see how the `useReducer` function is implemented you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/33068c9db9153a479bb29d138397cb9c32fabfdd/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L103-L110) (*rabbit hole warning*). ***Don't*** get too hung up on internal implementation details though. Regarding your second question, if you need to reference any values from the previous render you read up on [How to get the previous props or state](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) legacy docs.

Comment: @DrewReese For the second part your link explains how to save state value from previous render, which is fine. But, I am asking when state changes, it cause re-render and the _props remain unchanged_ during that re render. Those props are always gonna be `this.props`, then why do we need the second `props` parameter in `this.setState((state, props)=>{/*this.props*/})`?

Comment: Are you trying to use old outdated class-based React component code or are you trying to use current React code using hooks? The `useState` hook's state updater function doesn't take a second parameter, you can just reference the props object if you need to.

Comment: @DrewReese I am using old class based approach. Although I don't think it's outdated, yet.